# How to select a random values from the property file for Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Currently I'm working on Selenium WebDriver and using Java.
I have a Filter Section with many drop downs
In each drop down I have many options for all the drop downs.
All the options i have put it in a property file called Dropdown.properties

I have a property file (dropdown.properties) in the C: directory. In looks like

```
visualizationId=Day,Week,Month,Quarter,Semester,Year,RD Tech Group,ICC,Center,Software Pack,Product,Project,Customer PRs,Severity,Priority 
periodId=Last 4 Weeks,Last 52 Weeks,Date Range,Week Range,Month Range,Year To Date      
classificationId=All PRs,External PRs,Internal PRs,Customer PRs   

topographyId=Overall,Center,ICC

swpacksId=ADVIP,ADVLEG,ADVSEC,Boot,H323,IBC,MULTI,None,OneOS_EAD,PROXY,SBO,SIP,TDRE,VoDSL 
priorityId=Very Urgent,Urgent,Routine,Not Urgent,On Hold,Not Assigned 
severityId=Blocking,Major,Minor,Cosmetic,OLD PR
```

By using Java for each drop down it need to pick few values from the property file and it need to compare with the UI whether the options is present or not.

It should not check the order or something just want to check whether the randomly picked options from the property file is available in the UI

Please suggest me any solution.

I have read all the values from Property file using the code

```
Properties APPTEXT = new Properties();
Log.info("Getting Input from the Property file");
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\FilterSection\\dropdown.properties");
APPTEXT.load(fs);
System.out.println("Propertyfile : " +APPTEXT);
```

Could any one help me to pick few values from property file and need to check in UI.

Comment: What you need to do _first_ is read a property file - google "java read property file" and the first result will tell you how to. Once you have the values from the property file, now select a random set and verify against your UI.

Comment: I'm beginner in java could anyone give me sample code

Comment: @User11111: Avoid posting same question again and again

Comment: I'm not getting any answer if you have doubt plz check my other question as well and compare is it same or not

Comment: @User11111: All are around one thing *getting values from properties file comparing it with dropdwon values*

Comment: Can anyone help me for this. I strucked in this scenario. please anyone can help me

Comment: @Karna yes i will accept your point. but the problem i'm asking about to pick random values from property file. is that same with comparing the values??

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
public void getRandomOptions(dropdownName)
{
  Properties dropdown = new Properties();
  InputStream input = null;
  String returnString=null;
  input = new FileInputStream("yourconfig.properties");
  dropdown.load(input);
  String records = dropdown.getProperty(dropdownName);
  StringTokenizer breaker = new StringTokenizer(records, ",");
  int rLocation =(int) Math.random() * (breaker.countTokens()-1);
  for(int i=0;i<rLocation ;i++)
  {
      if(breaker.hasMoreTokens())
      returnString = breaker.nextToken();
  }

  return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this answer but always getting rLocation =0. When I debug , till breaker I can see all values separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

This code will retrieve all options

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("dropdown_id"));
Select select = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
for(WebElement option : options){
  System.out.println(option.getText());
  // Compare this value with value retrieved from properties file 
}
```